# CouchDB Sync not happening in GrocerySync-Android application

Tags: android, couchbase, couchbase-lite, couchbase-sync-gateway

I am new to couchDB,As a starting point I downloaded **GrocerySync-Android** and try to run on device(Samsung Galaxy S4) but data sync is happening.

This is what tried,

1)I have created "grocery-sync" in Data Buckets (couchbase-server)

2)I have changed Sync URL as shown below

```
public static final String SYNC_URL = "http://127.0.0.1:4984/grocery-sync";
```

When I change URL as shown above I am getting following Exception.

```
RemoteRequest io exception.  url: http://127.0.0.1:4984/grocery-sync/_local/022315cfb2e1f188613f04c99e49fbd537341d69
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://127.0.0.1:4984 refused
```

Then I tried changed my URL to:

```
http://127.0.0.1:5984/grocery-sync
```

Still I am getting same Connection refused exception.

Then I searched for issue some one suggested to use to following IP
**10.0.2.2** so URL become:

```
 http://10.0.2.2:4984/grocery-sync
```

If I use above URL I not getting Connection refused exception but I am getting following exception:

```
RemoteRequest: io exception.  url: http://10.0.2.2:4984/grocery-sync/_local/840159ea2a7e8f5a483f502f5ae79f2ad9f64ddf
org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to .. timed out
```

I am not getting what I am missing!!

3)When I start **sync_gateway**  following I can see on console,

```
**Reset guest user to config
Starting profile server on
Starting admin server on 127.0.0.1:4985
Starting server on localhost:4984..**
```

After that I wont see any logs.

Please let me what I am missing or doing wrong..Any help or guidance greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Sync Gateway or are you using CouchDB?  They are two separate products that aren't to be used together.

Comment: @borrden,Do want me to uninstall Sync GateWay and try.

Comment: No, that won't solve the problem but knowing which one you are using will affect the answer slightly.

Comment: I am bit confused here,Let me tell you my understanding,Please correct me If I am wrong.

Comment: 1)have installed Couchbase-server I think which is required.2)I have installed Couchbase Sync gateway(I have installed this see sync process).                                                                                                  What I want to achieve is add item to grocery list  sync it and uninstall app  when again I install   I want see last added item in list

Comment: Couchbase Server and CouchDB are two different products.  That's why things are confusing.  But I know what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sync gateway is not running on "localhost" in terms of your Android device.  That would mean that Sync Gateway is running **on** your device, but it's not.  It is running on your computer so you need to use the IP address of your computer and port 4984.

Comment: Ya your right,Now I have given my computer IP address and port 4984 but I am getting Connection timeout exception(At the time of sync). My mobile and my computer are connect to two different network is this reason I am getting connection timeout exception?

Comment: I can't say why you are getting a connection timeout.  Perhaps that port is not open on your firewall, but it sounds like a general connectivity issue between your two machines.